# Install packages from file on ubuntu one by one without stopping on errors

Tags: linux, ubuntu, software-installation

I want to do something similar to `xargs sudo apt install < pkglist`, but installing packages one by one, and giving a message without breaking when there is an error during a installation, or when a package name doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `apt-get` with `--ignore-missing`

`sudo apt-get --ignore-missing install $(cat packages-list.txt)`

or

`cat packages-list.txt | xargs sudo apt-get --ignore-missing install`

Comment: +1. Your `apt-get ... $(cat ...)` command subst will work (if you add the `install` option), but piping into `xargs apt-get` doesn't work properly because the pipe replaces stdin. If apt-get needs anything from stdin (e.g. an answer to a question), it will fail.   `sudo` will probably fail for the same reason.  You can use xargs' `-a` option to read the args from a file.  e.g. `xargs -a packages-list.txt sudo apt-get`.   even process subst will work: xargs -a <(cat packages.txt) sudo apt-get`.  the important thing is to avoid breaking stdin for apt-get.

Answer (score 0):

Using `xargs` , if `pkglist` contain a package per line, if note add a delimiter `-d '\n'` :

```
xargs -n 1 -- sudo apt install -y <  pkglist
```

`man xargs`:

```
-n max-args, --max-args=max-args
              Use at most max-args arguments per command line.
```